# how to count v1 v2 v3 and shown it as percentage?

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('1','0','1','1','0','1','0','0','1'),
                 v2 = c('0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0'),
                 v3 = c('1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','1'))
df
```

how to count v1 v2 v3 and shown it as percentage?
Expected Result v1 have 4 0s 5 1s (4/9 for 0 category; 5/9 for 1 category) v2 have 5 0s and 4 1s etc.
My trial as below:

```
length(df$`v1`[df$`v1` == 0])
```

[1] 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another base R option using `colMeans`

```
> colMeans(df > 0)
       v1        v2        v3
0.5555556 0.4444444 0.4444444
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~mean(. == '1')))

#         v1        v2        v3
#1 0.5555556 0.4444444 0.4444444
```

If you only have binary data you can convert data to numeric and use `colMeans` :

```
df %>% type.convert() %>% colMeans()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
colMeans(df=="1")
       v1        v2        v3 
0.5555556 0.4444444 0.4444444
```

Answer (score 2):

Also possible with `purrr` package functions:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  map_dbl(~ mean(.x == 1))

       v1        v2        v3 
0.5555556 0.4444444 0.4444444
```